# Efficient way to write repetitive instructions

Tags: javascript

I would like to write this part of my code in a more efficient way.

I have no idea what pattern to use in such situtation :

```
                l.match(/meite/) && (l = 'meite' + h);
                l.match(/rafael/) && (l = 'rafael' + h);
                l.match(/maicon/) && (l = 'maicon' + h);
                l.match(/player1(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player1' + h);
                l.match(/player2(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player2' + h);
                l.match(/player3(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player3' + h);
                l.match(/player4(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player4' + h);
                l.match(/player5(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player5' + h);
                l.match(/player6(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player6' + h);
                l.match(/player7(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player7' + h);
                l.match(/player8(?:\.|_)/) && (l = 'player8' + h);
```

What is good practice for such case ?

Comment: You could use a loop

Comment: What @GetOffMyLawn means is that you could put the arguments to the l.match and l = sections in an array or other structure and iterate through that structure to avoid rewriting "l.match(" and " && (l = " and " + h);".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a single regular expression and take the matched value.

```
var match = l.match(/meite|rafael|maicon|(player[1-8](?:\.|_))/);

if (match) l = match[0] + h;
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a loop to loop over each part.

```
// The first set of items
['meite', 'rafael', 'maicon'].forEach(i => l.match(new RegExp(i)) && (l = i + h))

// The second set of items
for(let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  l.match(new RegExp(`player${i}(?:\.|_)`) && (l = 'player' + i + h);
}
```

Comment: You could even set up an array of strings holding 'meite', 'rafael, maicon, player1, player 2, etc. and loop through the whole array in one go.

Comment: Opps, I'll delete my answer. Pretty much same thing, didn't realize you posted.

Comment: You could loop the first part too, iterating over an `Array` of `['meite', 'rafael', 'maicon']`.

Comment: @Raymond I think whoever voted you down was noticing you hadn't used your loop variable in your inside-of-the-loop code. You left it as "/meite/" literal.

Comment: I mean I get it, I understand. But sometime's people are really quick to jump on a new user trying to contribute.

Answer (score 3):

The last part could be done with a single regexp capturing the number of the player in a group.

```
let m = l.match(/player([1-8])(?:\.|_)/);
if (m) l = 'player' + m[1] + h;
```